# Get data from EF by sending type

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I managed to get data from entity framework by sending table name as string as below

```
Public Class EFORMv1(Of t As New)

Dim dx As New EF_ORMv1.MyEntity

Function SelectByKey(Table$,Field$,Value As Object) As IEnumerable(Of t)
        Dim s = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE " + Field + " = @p1"
        Dim r = dx.Database.SqlQuery(Of t)(s, New SqlParameter("@p1",Value))       
        Return r
End Function
End Class
```

I am using it like this

```
    Dim x As New EFORMv1(Of EF_ORMv1.CONTACT)
    Dim y = x.SelectByKey("CONTACT","NUM",1000).ToList
    Me.dataGridView1.DataSource = y
```

What i am searching for is not sending the table name as string as parameter, but since I send the type in [New EFORMv1(of EF_ORMv1.CONTACT)] so I would like to use it in SelectByKey() function

Is this possible?

Comment: You could use [`DbContext.Set<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx) to get the right table, but translating the WHERE clause to LINQ might be hard.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the type name of `t` as table name? i.e.: `GetType(t).Name`

Comment: @Georg : Using DbContext.Set(Of t) gives error : Type argument 't' does not satisfy the 'Class' constraint for type parameter 'TEntity'. 

If I used DbContext.Set(Of EF_ORMv1.CONTACT) it will work but will not be usefull

Comment: @TnTinmn : Thank you. that solve this question

Comment: @SamirIbrahim, you might as well just delete the question.  I see this as you just not knowing the right question to ask yourself to find the answer.

Comment: Delete it? is this ok?